# How to add one resume event for entire Cordova app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, events

I have a Cordova app with numerous HTML pages (probably a bad architecture, I know).  Is there any way I can have one resume event that covers the entire app?

I want to know when the app resumes.  I have added the resume event to one page and it works fine:

```
 document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
```

I would also have to add some html to each page - what is shown when resume occurs.  I'm trying to avoid doing the same thing on each page.

My app runs on both iOS and Android.

Thanks,
     - Jon

Answer (score 0):

just add the event listener in the first page that's loaded. Typically, you probably have a root component like app.component or similar, no?

Even when you navigate between page, the document will still be subscribed to that event and fire your handler.

If the app has multiple entry points, and you want to be sure you're subscribed in each route, then put the subscription in the constructor of a shared service.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no luck.  The root HTML page is index.html.  I added the event listener there.  I opened the app, navigated within the app, opened a different app, then reopened my app.  The listener on the index.html page did not fire.  Only when I have a listener on the exact HTML page that I was last using when I return to the app does the listener fire. Not sure how to "put the subscription in the constructor of a shared service" in Cordova.  - Jon

Comment: Can you share your file tree so I can see what's there? Just like a screenshot would work.

Comment: There are about 45 html pages in the app.  The initial entry point is index.html, then start.html, then todo.html.  There are six branches off todo.html, and several off those branches, one of which is tools.html.  If tools.html is the last used page, the user would come right back to that page when the app comes back to foreground.  By the way, I have a working solution attaching a resume event to each of the 45 pages - that's all I had to do since the same event handler can be used which points to the same html page (to verify their app passcode).  Thanks for your time!